# Can I read messages from gmail using gmail api and c#?

Tags: c#, gmail, gmail-api

I want read all messages in my gmail account using c# and gmail api.
Can I do this?
I read a lot of articles in [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/), but i couldn't read messages.
Also I want to read a body of messages or header. 
I will be very glad if someone can help me :)

I use this code snippet:

```
public static List<Message> ListMessages(GmailService service, String userId)
    {
        List<Message> result = new List<Message>();
        UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List(userId);

        do
        {
            try
            {
                ListMessagesResponse response = request.Execute();
                result.AddRange(response.Messages);
                request.PageToken = response.NextPageToken;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
            }
        } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));

        return result;
    }
```

And this:

```
foreach (var item in ListMessages(service,"me"))
                MessageBox.Show(item.Snippet);
```

But in a result I have empty message box.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me

```
 var inboxlistRequest = service.Users.Messages.List("your-email-address");
 inboxlistRequest.LabelIds = "INBOX";
 inboxlistRequest.IncludeSpamTrash = false;
 //get our emails   
 var emailListResponse = inboxlistRequest.Execute();
 foreach (var mail in emailListResponse.Messages)
 {
       var mailId = mail.Id;
       var threadId = mail.ThreadId;

       Message message = service.Users.Messages.Get("your-email-address", mailId).Execute();
       Console.WriteLine(message.Snippet);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should have no issue doing what you say.  I would suggest reading the documentation a bit more.

First you have to authenticate - the following shows how to do this with a service account (more details here https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server)

```
                    serviceAccountEmail = primaryLink.serviceEmailAddress;
                    certificate = new X509Certificate2(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "certs//" + primaryLink.certificate, primaryLink.certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

                    try
                    {
                        credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                        new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                        {
                            User = z.us.emailAccount,
                            Scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "https://mail.google.com/" }
                        }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                        if (credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result)
                        {
                            gs = new GmailService(
                            new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
                            {
                                ApplicationName = "Example",
                                HttpClientInitializer = credential
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception("gmail authentication Error.");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                    ListMessagesResponse respM = reqM.Execute();
                    if (respM.Messages != null)
                    {   
                         foreach (Message m in respM.Messages)
                         {}
                    }
```

Once you have the message List you can iterate through the messages and either use a MIME parser or traverse the message structure to get the header, body etc.

There are lots of posts in this forum which go through how to do that.

Comment: getting this {"Error:\"unauthorized_client\", Description:\"Unauthorized client or scope in request.\", Uri:\"\""} error. Is the email address a regular email address? Does the service account has to have domain user permission? Or the code sample works with any regular email address?

Comment: Yes this is a user email address.  The permissions of the Service Account will need to include access to that user. You do not have to use Service Accounts - you can get each user to authenticate and get a token etc for access.  You should check the Google Examples.

Comment: Simply with username and password it does not seem to be possible to download contacts/emails. I am working with this console application where user will not give any input. So I guess the the service account is the only way to do that. I did set the Viewer/Owner permission from the developer console but the error seems to be there.

Comment: You don't use user/password you use OAuth 2 authentication - read the details https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth

Comment: Yes, that was done with oAuth, but there is this error mentioned in the first comment. My last reply was to the comment that suggested username/password.
By the way, do you know if service account can be used with any regular gmail account or it has to be a domain account? Because for regular gmail accounts it is not possible to log in to the domain admin and hence permissions cannot be assigned. I have assigned permissions from the developer console tho. But the error still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a full example, without luck, but this is my working example. Based on https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides

1. Authenticate :  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server
2. get **ALL** emails
3. loop through all emails by Id, and request message etc.

here is the code snippet to get the first email's atachments, but you can simply loop over all **foundIds** to get all emails, and use **message.snippet** to get body  :

```
            List<string> foundIds = new List<string>();
            string outputDir = "/EXAMPLE/EXAMPLE/"; // your preferred Dir to save attachments to



            List<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Thread> resultThread = new List<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Thread>();
            UsersResource.ThreadsResource.ListRequest requestThread = service.Users.Threads.List("me");


            do
            {
                try
                {
                    ListThreadsResponse responseThread = requestThread.Execute();
                    resultThread.AddRange(responseThread.Threads);

                    foreach (var item in responseThread.Threads )
                    {
                        foundIds.Add(item.Id);
                    }

                    requestThread.PageToken = responseThread.NextPageToken;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                }
            } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(requestThread.PageToken));

            try
            {
                Message message = service.Users.Messages.Get("me", foundIds[0]).Execute();
                IList<MessagePart> parts = message.Payload.Parts;
                foreach (MessagePart part in parts)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(part.Filename))
                    {
                        String attId = part.Body.AttachmentId;
                        MessagePartBody attachPart = service.Users.Messages.Attachments.Get("me", foundIds[0], attId).Execute();

                        // Converting from RFC 4648 base64 to base64url encoding
                        // see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history
                        String attachData = attachPart.Data.Replace('-', '+');
                        attachData = attachData.Replace('_', '/');

                        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(attachData);
                        File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(outputDir, part.Filename), data);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at this article on how to handle the actual response structure. It can be somewhat complex with the way the Gmail API gives the results back to you.

https://sigparser.com/developers/email-parsing/gmail-api/

Answer (score -1):

@BlackCat, Your ListMessages looks good. Now, to get the message body, you have to decode MimeType "text/plain" or "text/html".  For eg:

```
public static void GetBody(GmailService service, String userId, String messageId, String outputDir)
    {
        try
        {
            Message message = service.Users.Messages.Get(userId, messageId).Execute();
            Console.WriteLine(message.InternalDate);
            if (message.Payload.MimeType == "text/plain")
            {
                byte[] data = FromBase64ForUrlString(message.Payload.Body.Data);
                string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                Console.WriteLine(decodedString);
            }
            else
            {
                IList<MessagePart> parts = message.Payload.Parts;
                if (parts != null && parts.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (MessagePart part in parts)
                    {
                        if (part.MimeType == "text/html")
                        {
                            byte[] data = FromBase64ForUrlString(part.Body.Data);
                            string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                            Console.WriteLine(decodedString);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("----");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: MessagePart can contain other parts that have parts of the body... easiest approach is with recursion